# How can i submit the form after showing the message?

Tags: javascript, validation, customization

How can i submit or release the form after using event.preventDefault() ?? I am trying to add sweet alert in this form before submit the form data. Please help

```
 // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
    'use strict'

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
        .forEach(function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Are you sure?',
                        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                        icon: 'warning',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            //what should i do ????
                        }
                    })

                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated')

            }, false)
        })
})()
```

Comment: form.submit() would do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: solution : 
//what should i do 
form.submit()

Comment: Are you trying to have your alert show before the form submission or after?